# Accidentally deleted /usr/share directory... what can I do to fix it?

Tags: macos

A botched terminal command left me without a `/usr/share` folder. Most things seem to be running ok (although I haven't restarted since, so it's not clear if I'd have errors on reboot). There are already a few things wrong though, such as not being able to backspace in zshell, and emacs refusing to start up (giving me a `Cannot open terminfo database file` message). I'm not sure what in all is stored there, so I don't know what if anything I can do to reinstall necessary files, etc. Alternatively, is there a repair utility built in to OS X that might be able to restore at least some of the most essential things?

Note: I unfortunately don't have any backup software installed. Live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Tough break.  If you have never backed up with Time Machine, then you should look at [this link](http://data-security-freeware.blogspot.com/2011/05/truly-free-mac-data-recovery-software.html) for a post on free undelete utilities.  Or you can ask a colleague to compress their /usr/share folder if you're desperate.  Last suggestion would be setting up a VM with your OSX version and copying it from there, but if you don't have Fusion or Parallels already installed, they'll ask for a reboot.

Good luck.